# Magento 2 - How to get additional options product from quote item

Tags: magento2, custom-options, magento2.2.2, attribute-options

I have some **Vitrual product** with options, I need to get his options but I can just get the `info_buyRequest` instead of `additional_options`

Here is my code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

//This doesn't work
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

//This doesn't work too
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

//This return something
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}

//Here I try to get the product options but no way

$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
    $customOptions = $options['options']; // error here, line 44
    if (!empty($customOptions)) {
        foreach ($customOptions as $option) {
            $optionTitle = $option['label'];
            $optionId = $option['option_id'];
            $optionType = $option['type'];
            $optionValue = $option['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: options in
>   /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml
>   on line 44

[image]

> `quote_item_option` table > `additional_options` code

Comment: try with `$item->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest');`

Comment: I replaced `$item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());` with `$item->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest');` but it doesn't work, he breaks the page

Comment: Did you ever solved the problem @PЯINCƏ

Answer (score 3):

Please use below to get additional_options

```
$options = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');
```

Comment: It doesn't work and this code breaks the page (white page)

Comment: If it's showing white page then check log and see what is causing

Comment: Yes, I know but I have nothing. As you see the error in my question I can display the Exceptions but with your solution no !

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> $options = $item->getBuyRequest();

**Instead of**

> $options =
>   $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the product `id`, `sku`, `qty` the `info_buyRequest` data, but not the options !

Answer (score 2):

You can use it is work for me,

```
$additionalOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')
echo $additionalOptions->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this wasn't answered the above solutions are missing the call to get the options.

```
$item->getBuyRequest()->getAdditionalOptions()
```

Comment: `getBuyRequest` expects two parameters, and you have given none. This code does break my page.